# TYPO3 v11 - Template, TypoScript Setup, Overriding, multiple extensions or sitepackages

Tags: templates, typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-11.x, site-packages

I have correctly installed 3 extensions in TYPO3 v11:

- Bootstrap Package
- distri_cdg82
- base_theme

The last 2 were created on [sitepackagebuilder](https://sitepackagebuilder.com/).

In the TYPO3 backend of my project, I went into Template => Info/Modify => Edit the whole template record => Includes.

In "Include static (from extensions)" section, I have selected the 3 extensions (see photo).

I expect the following behavior: `base_theme` overrides `distri_cdg82` which overrides `bootstrap_package`. And of course, only for the files added.

So, it works when I add for example something in `base_theme/Ressources/Templates/ContentElements/Example.html`

But, if my `base_theme/Ressources/Templates` folder is empty and I add something in `distri_cdg82/Ressources/Templates/ContentElements/Example.html`, this file should appear but is not...

So I need someone's help!

I guess I miss something in setup.typoscript files or something.

[image]

Comment: Should work like you described it. Did you check for typos and/or wrong assignments?

Comment: @ThomasLöffler, Thanks but where should I check this ?...

Comment: Are your extensions overwriting each other? Or do they complement each other?
The paths for possible template files are traversed in reverse order until a matching file is found. However, if you set the respective path to *the same* position with all extensions (i.e. the index is the same), then you *overwrite* the paths instead of building a cascade with fallbacks.
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html#t3-cobj-fluidtemplate-layoutRootPaths